# How do I mount a 70" TV to wall when the studs are in the wrong place?

Tags: walls, television, mount

I want to mount a 70" tv (68lbs) to a wall, but all the wall mounts I find need to be mounted between studs. The studs above my fireplace are 16" apart, but there's one stud about 2" off center of the center of the fireplace.

If I mount the bracket so that there's a stud on either side, I'll end up with a TV significantly off center... What are my options?

Should I just use a piece of 3/4" plywood and hang it between the existing studs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Most every mount I've seen has several holes through which it can be secured to studs. This is to account for different stud spacing, as well as allow for several lateral positions so that the TV is not off center.

Double check your mount instructions, to ensure it will not accommodate your stud spacing. I'm very suspicious that the mount says it must be mounted between studs, as you want that kind of load directly into at least one stud.

If it won't, then attaching 3/4" plywood to the studs, and the mount to the plywood, is indeed the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, my 70" TV mount is like you say; full of holes to allow for almost any stud configuration. The clips which attach to the TV can also slide along the mount, too, but that may be a feature of the particular mount.

Comment: I have mounted several with mount off center in order to get a stud and then just slid the tv over so it is slightly off center of the mount but center of the space.

Answer (score 1):

Every time I have run across this problem I have taken a board about the same hight as the wall mount bracket and mounted the board across 3 studs.  Then paint it the same color as the wall if necessary (most if not all of it will be hidden behind your massive TV anyways).  3 studs is probably way more than needed to hold the weight, but when hanging very expensive things above people's heads better to go for too strong than not strong enough.

Then you can safely mount that bracket anywhere you want along the board.

The board also gives a nice spot to mount a power bar, and any small electronics like an Android box without mucking around with drywall anchors.

Answer (score 0):

[image] easy fix. I purchased a wall mount extender from Mounting Dream. They have a Facebook page or you can order on Amazon. Let's you extend mount from that standard size all the way out to like 24 inches for those of us whose wall studs happen to be spaced awkwardly.

Comment: I think there is a decent answer in here, but it feels more like spam.