# Hanging a TV board ( 70" x 72" ) and 100 lbs

Tags: television, board

I need to hang the large TV board onto my wall. The wall is 1/2" drywall mounted onto 3/4" thick wood furring strips which are mounted onto cement block. 
The TV board has 3 wood blocks that are to be mounted onto the drywall and will marry with the three blocks mounted to the rear of the TV board.
None of the blocks line up with the wood furring strips. I feel I need to add additional anchors besides the 3 wood blocks with a TV board this heavy. What are my options to mount this large board with confidence?
Thank you.

Steve Cawley

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I mount a 70" TV to wall when the studs are in the wrong place?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/115450/how-do-i-mount-a-70-tv-to-wall-when-the-studs-are-in-the-wrong-place)

Comment: Seems like you're trying to use a "TV board" that isn't suited to the task. I'd skip the blocks and just mount the board directly to the wall, then mount your TV. Please post photos of this board. It's not something I'm familiar with.

Comment: what is a TV board?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to repair a closet treatment that pulled the drywall screws from the wall. I wanted to ensure a more solidly attached french cleat and used what I've found are called "self drilling wall anchors."

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HNKG7ZH) sells a pack of 30 anchors with matching screws, which are rated for fifty pounds capacity. I used many, spaced about six to eight inches to prevent too-close breakout.

As with your configuration, there was insufficient space behind the wall to allow the entire anchor to thread into the wallboard. I resolved that problem by using one anchor to drill the "pilot hole" then snipped off the pilot ends from the anchors being placed. This allows the anchors to be installed flush with the wall and permits the maximum strength.

[image: self drilling wall anchor]

Comment: The anchors you reverence are inadequate for holding the weight of a large TV. I have used them many times for light weight items but they not good at holding anything of significant weight. They are only holding onto the drywall with that slightly wide thread and the process of screwing them into the drywall weakens the drywall as it twists in. Just my experience with them. I use these -  https://www.amazon.com/TOGGLER-SNAPTOGGLE-Zinc-Plated-Channel-Fastener/dp/B0051IBBUE?SubscriptionId=AKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q&tag=duckduckgo-ffsb-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B0051IBBUE

Comment: spacing and quantity makes a difference. I've re-mounted a rather heavy closet organizer that was held in with drywall screws, but I spaced the new anchors on 6 inch spacing, increasing the quantity over the original installation.

Answer (score 0):

cut holes in in the drywall and use expanding bolts and spacers to mount the wood blocks to the cement block wall.